# ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE and DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE is not returning correct values

Tags: sql-server, encryption, password-encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt using following code:

```
declare @decryptedValue nvarchar(4000)
declare @encryptedValue varbinary(8000)

SET @encryptedValue  = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008','SomeValue')
Set @decryptedValue = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008',@encryptedValue)

print @decryptedValue
```

But the decrypted value is not what I passed in ('SomeValue') , but some encrypted charecter 潓敭慖畬e.

Strangely if I create two functions like below it works:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Encrypt(@str nvarchar(4000))
    RETURNS varbinary(8000)
    AS BEGIN 
     DECLARE @res varbinary(8000)
     SET @res = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008',@str)
     RETURN (@res)
     END
    GO



    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Decrypt(@encrypt varbinary(8000))
    RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
    AS
    BEGIN 
     DECLARE @res nvarchar(4000)
     SET @res = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008',@encrypt)
     RETURN(@res)
    END
    GO


declare @x nvarchar(4000)
declare @code varbinary(8000)
SET @code =   dbo.Encrypt('SomeValue')
Print @code
set @x = dbo.Decrypt(@code)
print @x
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is with nvarchar, if change it to varchat it works fine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you're encrypting a varchar value and casting the decrypted value to an nvarchar. Those two datatypes have different byte structures. It's easily fixed, though (literally one character):

```
declare @decryptedValue nvarchar(4000)
declare @encryptedValue varbinary(8000)

SET @encryptedValue  = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008',N'SomeValue') --note the "N" before "N'SomeValue'"
Set @decryptedValue = DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SQL SERVER 2008',@encryptedValue)

print @decryptedValue
```

As to why it worked with your functions, because the arguments to the functions are themselves typed, you're getting an implicit conversion. So, when you provide `'SomeValue'` to the `Encrypt` function, it gets converted to an nvarchar version of that and *that* is passed to `encryptbypassphrase()`.